# How to convert go type Cookie to type string

Tags: go

In go I have a function:

```
func UrlGET(url string, headers string) string { // inputs are url and headers for a http request
    ...
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    ...
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    if rc := resp.Cookies(); len(rc) > 0 {
        return string(rc)
    }
    return ""
}
```

However, you cannot convert type Cookie (`[]*http.Cookie` to type string (`cannot convert rc (type []*http.Cookie) to type string`). What would be an alternative or another way to convert to type string, ideally I would still return type string. I'm relatively new to go so at a bit of a wall as to what else to try.

Ideally, it would return like `cookie=some_cookie_value` as a string.

Comment: There are many possible ways to encode the slice of cookies as a string.   Edit the question to show inputs and your expected result. Perhaps the header value is what you need.

Comment: @CeriseLimón edited!

Comment: Loop through the cookies encoding the [Name](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Cookie.Name) and [Value](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Cookie.Value) fields to the desired format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want one big string, you can do:

```
package main
import "net/http"

func main() {
   r, e := http.Get("https://stackoverflow.com")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer r.Body.Close()
   s := r.Header.Get("Set-Cookie")
   println(s)
}
```

Or you could build a map:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "net/http"
)

func main() {
   r, e := http.Get("https://stackoverflow.com")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer r.Body.Close()
   m := make(map[string]string)
   for _, c := range r.Cookies() {
      m[c.Name] = c.Value
   }
   fmt.Println(m)
}
```

- https://golang.org/pkg/net/http#Response.Cookies
- https://golang.org/pkg/net/http#Response.Header